# I cannot echo contents of file through fgets(filename).

Tags: php, fgets, fread

Here is my code. I don't know why I am not getting any thing on page.Suggest me a mode in which if I want to run my code everytime, it should append at the end. and i should also be able to read from it

```
<?php 

$a=fopen("Welcome.txt","a+");
fwrite($a, "abc");
echo fgets($a);

fclose($a);

?>
```

Comment: This certainly won't work. You open the file for _appending_. That means you have to close the file after writing to it, then reopen it for _reading_. Which does make sense, since you want to read _from the start_.

Comment: @arkascha what mode should i give instead of 'a+' so that everytime i run my code, it appends at the last of the existing file,without erasing previous contents?

Comment: Mode `'a+'` is perfectly fine. I did not say you should change that. But if you open a file for appending you cannot read from it. Appending and reading is something different.

Comment: I got it. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong mode for [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

```php
$a = fopen("Welcome.txt","r");
var_dump($a);
```

`a+` will "Open for reading and writing" and "If the file does not exist, attempt to create it".

Comment: what mode should i give instead of 'a+' so that everytime i run my code, it appends at the last of the existing file,without erasing previous contents and without attempting to create the new file?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `fgets` use `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` instead of `fwrite` IMO it's a lot cleaner and easier to understand.